# Prove that $(X \cap Y) \cup Z = (X \cup Z) \cap (Y \cup Z)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've only the definition of union, intersection, subset, and complement available to me.

$$(X \cap Y) \cup Z = (X \cup Z) \cap (Y \cup Z)$$

$(X \cap Y) = \left\{a: a \in X, ~ a \in Y\right\}$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
(X \cap Y) \cup Z &=& \left\{a: a \in X ~ \text{or} ~ a \in Y\right\} \cup \left\{a: a \in Z\right\}\\
&=& \left\{a: a \in X ~ \text{or} ~ a \in Y, ~ \text{and} ~ a \in Z \right\} \tag1 \\
&=& \left\{a: a \in X~ \text{and} ~ a \in Z, ~ \text{or}, ~ a \in Y ~ \text{and} ~ a \in Z \right\} \tag2\\
&=&\left\{a: a \in X~ \text{and} ~ a \in Z\right\} \cap \left\{a: ~ a \in Y ~ \text{and} ~ a \in Z \right\}\tag3\\
&=& (X \cup Z) \cap (Y \cup Z)\tag4
\end{eqnarray}$$

I numbered those last few lines to make it easier to point out my blunders. I've never proven anything with sets before, so it probably doesn't make any sense. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have $a\in X$ **or** $a\in Y$ in the third line, which should be **and**. Sorry, @Vladhagen, but your first sentence read badly the first time I read it, now I get it. Maybe put some bold in there and I can delete my comment.

Comment: The intuition here is that anything in $Z$ is in both sides. If an element is not in $Z$ it needs to be in both $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in essence what you have, just with the **and** and the **or** changed. Note that Union coincides with "or" and Intersection coincides with "and."
$(X \cap Y) \cup Z = (X \cup Z) \cap (Y \cup Z)$.

$(X \cap Y) = \left\{a: a \in X, ~ a \in Y\right\}$

$(X \cap Y) \cup Z = \left\{a: a \in X ~ \text{and} ~ a \in Y\right\} \cup \left\{a: a \in Z\right\}$

1.................... $ = \left\{a: (a \in X ~ \text{and} ~ a \in Y), ~ \text{or} ~ a \in Z \right\} $

2.................... $= \left\{a: (a \in X~ \text{or} ~ a \in Z), ~ \text{and}, ~ (a \in Y ~ \text{or} ~ a \in Z) \right\}$

3.................... $= \left\{a: (a \in X~ \text{or} ~ a \in Z\right\} \cap \left\{a: ~ a \in Y ~ \text{or} ~ a \in Z \right\}$

4.................... $= (X \cup Z) \cap (Y \cup Z)$

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised what I was doing wasn't completely dodgy!

Answer (score 0):

Looks okay, but you've swapped `and` and `or`. Remember that:

$A \cap B$ is the set of elements that are in $A$ **and** $B$. If $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A$ **and** $x \in B$.

$A \cap B$ is the set of elements that are in $A$ **or** $B$. If $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A$ **and** $x \in B$.

Note that this means that intersection is a **subset** of union: If $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A \cup B$, because if ($x \in A$ and $ x \in B$) holds, then $(x \in A$ or $x \in B$) also holds.

Comment: Thanks. In speaking of subsets, I wonder whether this can be proven by showing each is subset of the other? That's how initially thought it would be done.

Comment: I think so. if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, then $A=B$. The way to do this is to show that if $a \in A$, then $a \in B$. That means $A \subseteq B$. The other way around, show that if $b \in B$, then $b \in A$. Then $B \subseteq A$. Then you're done. That's the way to do it.