# Question about elementary set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How can I explain that
>
> $A\cup(B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$
>
> is true?

Comment: As with most set theoretical questions, you should start with an element on the LHS/RHS and show inclusion on the other side.

Comment: Remember the definitions

Comment: The proof based on the definitions is pretty straightforward - if you are looking for some other form of understanding, you might try drawing a Venn diagram for $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660058/prove-that-x-cap-y-cup-z-x-cup-z-cap-y-cup-z?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

We show inclusions of both sides.

Suppose $x \in A \cup (B \cap C).$

If $x \in A$, then $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in  A \cup C$. But then $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

If $ \in B \cap C$, then $x \in B$ and $x \in C$. But then we have also $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

Hence we have $A \cup (B \cap C) \subset (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

Now suppose $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

We then have $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in A \cup C$. If $x \notin A$ then $x \in B \cap C$.

Hence, we have $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$ and $(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C) \subset A \cup (B \cap C)$.

We now conclude that $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can start by saying what does each side represent

1. LHS: all the $x$'s that are either in $A$ or in the intersection of $B$ and $C$ (or in both).
2. RHS: all the $x$'s that are either in $A$ or $B$ (or both) *and* either in $A$ or $C$ (or both).

Now take an $x$ on the LHS.

1. If it is in $A$ then it is also in the RHS (it is straightforward).
2. If it is in the intersection of $B$ and $C$ but not in $A$ then it is in $A \cup B$ *and* in $A \cup C$ and thus also in $(A\cup B)\cap(A \cup C)$.

Therefore in both cases you conclude that it is also in the RHS (you can write the above reasoning in more detail). Thus $$A\cap(B\cup C)\subseteq (A\cup B)\cap(A \cup C)\tag1$$Now repeat the above process starting with an $x$ that is in the RHS to show that $$(A\cup B)\cap(A \cup C) \subseteq A\cap(B\cup C) \tag2$$ Combining (1) and (2) you will have the required equality, i.e. that $$A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A \cup C)$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in LHS$. Then there are two cases to consider:

**I** $\quad$ $x \in A$. But then $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in A \cup C$. So $x \in (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

**II** $\quad$ $x \in B \cap C$. But then $x \in B$ and $x \in C$. So $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C$).

In either case, $x \in RHS$. Hence $LHS \subseteq RHS$.

The proof of the opposite inclusion is similar.

Answer (score 1):

The left hand side means $\{ x \mid x \in A \text{ or } x \in \{y \mid y \in B \text{ and } y \in C\}\}$

The right hand side is $\{x \mid x \in \{y \mid y \in A \text{ or } y \in B\} \text{ and } x \in \{y \mid y \in A \text{ or } y \in C\}\}$

Take an $x$ in the right. Now I find it easiest to work with the logic in it. We know $(x\in A \text{ or } x \in B) \text{ and } (x\in A \text{ or } x \in B) \\=  (x\in A \text{ and } (x\in A \text{ or } x \in B)) \text{ or } (x \in C \text{ and } (x\in A \text{ or } x \in B))\\ = (x \in A) \text{ or } (x \in A \text{ and } x \in C) \text{ or } (x \in B \text{ and } x \in C)\\ = (x \in A) \text{ or } (x \in B \text{ and } x \in C)$

These conditions are exactly the LHS therefore the two sides must be equal.